# How do I define function dynamically in Erlang/Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have `GenServer` which basically only handles `cast`.

So I don't have any functions which track state of server (as I don't need it).

The problem: while I don't need it in production, I need some testing.

I can define `handle_call` just to track server state in test suit, however, this feels wrong.

I thought of adding this `handle_call` function at runtime before my test suit, so I can track server state in certain cases of casts sequences.

Tried to find some useful data googling, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since GenServer is an OTP special process, you can use tools from the `:sys` module to introspect it's state and behaviour. One of those functions is `:sys.get_state/1` that allows you to access the state of the process without defining any specific callbacks in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you don't want the compiled module to contain the given `handle_call` function to appear in production? In eunit, for example, you can surround functions you only want to exist for testing with `ifdef(TEST).`/`endif.`. If you're using rebar3, and run eunit tests with `rebar3 eunit`, rebar3 defines `TEST` for you automatically, so that's all you have to do (as well as include the `eunit.hrl`). Otherwise, you can define it manually at compile-time.

See http://erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html for more information.